# Google cloud command to list billing details

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The gcloud billing command provides very brief information about a billing account.

```
gcp@auto-tagging-188806:~$ gcloud alpha billing accounts describe xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
displayName: My Billing Account
name: billingAccounts/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
open: true
```

I wish to be able to list more information such as the following:
Billing account ID, Billing account name, Payments account ID, Emails of invoice delivery, Bill-to address, Payments profile ID, Payments users, etc

Is there a command that could display more information on a billing account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't currently possible through command line. Anyways, [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to) you have the documentation about how you get different information about the billing question.